# docker compose use ipvlan with static address for a DHCP server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, macvlan

I'd like to run a docker-compose made of a few containers one of which should act as a DHCP server and assign IP addresses to a few devices attached to a bridge directly plugged into one of the docker-compose host interface.

I  think I could use macvlan or ipvlan - the latter being my preference, ipvlan seems to do exactly what I wish, with the only excpetion of this gateway/ip_range business.

I am a bit confused about why they are needed in the first place, all I'd like to do is to assign a static ip address to the container interface and have the DHCP server listening at that interfacec. I am starting to question myself wether ipvlan/macvlan are the right solution or otherwise.

In short, is there a way to assign a static ip address to a ipvlan interface ? I've found a few solutions over the internet but none works with docker compose v3.

Comment: But SO is for programming questions

Comment: Please ask the question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). I can't vote4close because of bounty.

Answer (score 3):

[Docker Compose v3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) should allow defining custom network plugins and configurations, including [Macvlan](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/macvlan/) and [IPvlan](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/ipvlan/). Between Macvlan and IPvlan, the latter has advantages such as not needing MAC addresses, which can be useful in large-scale scenarios.

Assigning a static IP to a container using Docker Compose v3 should also be straightforward. You can use the [`ipv4_address` setting](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address) under the network.
Create a Docker network outside of Docker Compose, for instance an IPvlan network named `ipvlan_net`, associated with the `eth0` interface on the Docker host:

```bash
docker network create -d ipvlan \
  --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 \
  --gateway=192.168.1.1 \
  -o parent=eth0 \
  ipvlan_net
```

The `gateway/ip_range` is required for routing. The gateway is used to forward traffic that is not destined for the local network. That becomes especially important if your containers need to access external networks or the internet.

Then configure your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  dhcp-server:
    image: your_dhcp_image
    networks:
      ipvlan_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.10
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN 

networks:
  ipvlan_net:
    external: true
```

- The [`external` configuration](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#external) under `networks` ensures that Docker Compose uses the pre-existing `ipvlan_net` network.
- Make sure the static IP address assigned (`192.168.1.10` in this example) does not conflict with any existing addresses or ranges you have configured for DHCP lease.